# JQuery Horizontal Opposite Slide Functionality

Tags: jquery

Im interested in implementing a JQuery Solution for a Animated Horizontal Slide Function.

In the following example various "tetimonials" text slide from opposite directions at a specified interval.

The following example is in flash:

http://gsgpainting.com/contactUs.html  (check the left column onload)

My simple question is: Does a  JQuery tool exist for this? Or is there an easy JavaScript solution to implment this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course it possible. give me a few minutes and ill make a fiddle for it ^_^

ok try something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/t5jyM/

html:

```
<div id='left-box'>
    <div class='msg'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam euismod sem facilisis neque blandit </div>
    <div class='msg'>Vivamus nec tellus dui. Etiam pretium, libero sed eleifend laoreet, arcu massa suscipit nisl, sed </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var delay = 1000;

$('.msg').each(function(){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.delay(delay).show('slide')
    delay = delay+1000;
})
```

and if you want from two directions, check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sCNUL/

 UR WELCOME ^_^

Comment: @Neal how would you make it slide in from either directions as in the example?

Comment: @Paul, you can play around with [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) after the delay instead of show :-D

Comment: @Paul look at the 2nd demo on the animate page for an example

Comment: @Neal yes but how would you control from what direction this animates?

Comment: @Paul see my earlier comment ^_^

Comment: @Neal I see how that 2nd example has the amimation moving right then left based upon button click events. In your example you have it to run without any click event.

Comment: Well that would a great help.  I wish I had 12 hours to kill to figure this out.  Im really new to JQuery thanks
!

Comment: @Paul i added a new example to my answer. see if that works for u ^_^

Comment: @Neal I see that you added children to this, I wouldnt have figured that out, thanks!  I see that this only runs with JQuery 1.5.1 with JQuery UI 1.8.9   I have 1.5 which wont work.  Im seeing alot of places to download this, any clue about the best place to download both of these?

Comment: @Paul, changed the 2nd fiddle a little ^_^

Comment: @Paul, my newsest example uses 1.4.2 it can work with anything 1.4.2 and above. what version do you have?

Comment: @Neal I got 1.5 hmmm the originial Fiddle you sent didnt work right w/ 1.4.2 but yes I just tested the opposite annimation and that works!

Comment: @Neal for some reason this isnt working in my page.  Could you tell me if I need to change something in the JavaScript?  I have this JavaScript w/in Script Tags:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/LXsUL/

Comment: @Neal yes in JSFiddle it works, Im using IE 8  I wasnt sure if I needed to modify that JavaScript for the Page

Comment: @Paul, did you try it on your actual page?

Comment: @Neal Yes thats where its failing, do you want to check it out in FireBug?

Comment: @PAul -- sure. what is the URL?

Comment: @Neal http://www.davincispainting.com/generalcontact.aspx its going to be w/in here: <div id="rightcontentboxx">

Comment: ok. i see no js code for it. i have to leave soon. so please show me where that is

Comment: i found ur issue.   wrap the code around with `$(function(){/*code*/})`

Comment: @Neal ahhh ya see! I figured I was missing something for that. Perfect, it works!

Comment: @Paul, im on the site and i dont see it working, but ill take ur word for it ^_^, ur welcome

Comment: @Neal yea Im going to upload that, I know for sure it works locally

Comment: @Paul i would like to see the final working one eventually :-)

Comment: @Neal it should be there now, if you check out davincispainting.com Contact Us- General Contact.   I've got another issue now, that I didnt even realize until I looked at this HomePage with a larger monitor.  I've been using this small laptop the whole time.  The Logo is way out of wack, and Im not sure how to address that without developing on a large monitor.

Comment: @Paul, i noticed that. i thought it was on purpose :-p

Comment: @Neal lol thats funny.  yea everything looks perfect on my small-screened laptop.

Comment: @Neal no worries I got it all fixed up

Comment: @Paul. ow. look at it in chrome

Comment: @Neal seriously even now? I dont have chrome